# JAVA - reading character with SCANNER

Tags: java

Here is the problem that I'm working on.

We have to ask the user to enter a string, and then enter a character (any character would be fine). And then count the number of times that character appears in the scanner.

I cannot figure out how to add character to scanner. We haven't done arrays yet so I don't wanna go there but this is what I have done so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Counter {

   public static void main (String args[]){

        String a;
        char b;
        int count;
        int i;


        Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);


        System.out.println("Enter a string");

        a = s.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter a character");

        b = s.next().charAt(0);

        count = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <= a.length(); i++){

            if (b == s.next().charAt(b)){

                count += 1;

        System.out.println(" Number of times the character appears in the string is " + count);

                else if{

                    System.out.println("The character appears 0 times in this string");
            }


            }

        }
```

I know this is incorrect but I cannot figure this out right now.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I would strongly recommend starting with code that *compiles*, even if it might not do what you want yet. At least with compiling code, you can run it to see if it works. Your code just needs some minor modifications to compile.

Answer (score 1):

To verify your inputs [String, char] use a while loop for getting the character from the user. Basically you will check whether user enters **a string of length 1** for character input.
Here is the *compiling* and *running* version of your code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Counter
{
    public static void main ( String args[] )
    {
        String a = "", b = "";
        Scanner s = new Scanner( System.in );

        System.out.println( "Enter a string: " );
        a = s.nextLine();
        while ( b.length() != 1 )
        {
            System.out.println( "Enter a single character: " );
            b = s.next();
        }

        int counter = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++ )
        {
            if ( b.equals(a.charAt( i ) +"") )
                counter++;
        }
        System.out.println( "Number of occurrences: " + counter );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the for loop condition should be changed to :

```
for (i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
```

The index starts from 0, but when you count length you start from 1. Therefore you don't need '='.

Second, in the for loop, you only need to do one thing: compare each character of a with b:

```
if (b == a.charAt(i))
    count += 1;
```

Here, compared with the other solution, char is cheaper than String to be compared.

Third, after the for loop, output depends on count:

```
if (count > 0)
    System.out.println(" Number of times the character appears in the string is "
                        + count);
else // must be count == 0
    System.out.println("The character appears 0 times in this string");
```